# Delete works for one API-Controller, but not for the other (almost identical code)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating methods in my web api to be able to remove users, but the same method that I'm using for my other controller is working? I'm reciving a 405 - method not allowed.

PostController (working):

```
public IHttpActionResult DeletePost(int id)
{
     Post post = controller.Post(id);
     if (post == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     controller.DeletePost(id);
        return Ok(post);
}
```

UserController (not working):

```
public IHttpActionResult DeleteUser(string username)
{
      User user = controller.User(username);
      if (user == null)
      {
         return NotFound();
      }

      controller.DeleteUser(username);
      return Ok(user);
 }
```

This is the DAL for the Delete method of the UserController:

```
public void DeleteUser(string username)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=X;User Id=X;Password=X;");
     string sql = "DELETE FROM [User] WHERE Username=@Username";
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

NOTE: The query works directly in SQL Management Studio

Edit for angular part (note: they are in the same controller and template):

```
$scope.delete = function (id) {
        Post.delete({ id: id }, function () {
            $scope.getPosts();
        }
    );
    };

    $scope.deleteUser = function (id) {
        User.delete({ id: id }, function () {
            console.log("delete button triggered");
            $scope.getUsers();
        }
    );
    };
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by _not working_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? Be more specific about your problems..

Comment: do you use the same http method?

Comment: I already wrote that I recieve a 405 error message ;), I'm using angularjs, will add code for that too in a sec

Comment: It could be that it's due to the parameter problem. Try: `User.delete({ id: id.toString() }`

Comment: In angular or the web-api?

Comment: in angular, or update the web api to accept `int`

Comment: Well the id is username so it must be a `string`

Comment: so just update angular

Comment: Now it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Comment: Found and solved the problem myself thanks anyway!